# How to declare an attribute that start with [ and end with ]?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, font-awesome

How I can declare an attribute with []?
I use font-awesome and want to change the attribute [icon] from `faLock`to `faUnlock` onclick but with Angular/Typescript it just show the following error:

```
ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '[icon]' is not a valid attribute name.
```

This is the Typescript code:

```
togglePasswordI.setAttribute('[icon]', 'faUnlock');
```

This is the HTML Element:

```
<fa-icon [icon]="faLock" [fixedWidth]="true" size="lg" aria-hidden="true" id="toggle_password" (click)="toggle_password($event)"></fa-icon>
```

Answer (score 2):

Bind it to a variable and toggle its value:

```
<fa-icon [icon]="iconName" [fixedWidth]="true"></fa-icon>
```

In the TS:

```
iconName: string;

// ...

this.iconName = someConditionToFulfill ? 'faLock' : 'faUnlock';
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<i (click)="clicked = !clicked" [ngClass]="clicked ? 'fa fa-lock': 'fa fa-unlock'"></i>
```

Component

```
//Declare clicked false
clicked = false;
```

Example Here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pgc7st

Answer (score 0):

```
<fa-icon [icon]="icon" [fixedWidth]="true" size="lg" aria-hidden="true" id="toggle_password" (click)="toggle_password($event)"></fa-icon>
```

In ts declare a variable for icon:

```
    icon: string = 'faLock';

    toggle_password(event) {
    // your code
      this.icon = 'faUnlock';
    }
```